# Kotlin constructor properties and calling different superclass constructors

Tags: exception, kotlin

I'd like to use a kotlin data class as an exception, which seems fine:

```
data class MyException(val extraData: Any) : RuntimeException()
```

I'd also like to be able to pass in a `cause` to the super class in those cases where one exists. Unfortunately, data classes can only have `val`/`var` in their primary constructor, and since the default constructor calls the no-args `RuntimeException()` constructor, it seems that I simply cannot do this without always requiring `cause` to be passed, *and* stored as a field in my class, which I don't want.

What I want is something like this:

```
data class MyException(val extraData: Any) : RuntimeException() {
    constructor(extraData: Any, cause: Throwable) : this(extraData) super(cause) {}
}
```

It seems that even if I don't use a data class, I still can't use the convenient `var`/`val` constructor helpers, since they can only be on a primary constructor which must chose which super constructor to use. The best I can come up with is this, which is quite verbose:

```
class MyException : RuntimeException {
    val extraData: Any

    constructor(extraData: Any) {
        this.extraData = extraData
    }

    constructor(extraData: Any, cause: Throwable) : super(cause) {
        this.extraData = extraData
    }
}
```

Am I missing something? Is there really no way of conditionally calling a different super-class constructor based on overloaded constructors and still being able to use the `var`/`val` parameter syntax? If so, why? Are there better ways of doing this sort of thing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want is perfectly doable with a regular class like this:

```
class MyException(val extraData: Any, cause: Throwable? = null) : RuntimeException(cause)
```

In here you have a primary constructor which always takes in `extraData` and makes a property out of it. It also takes in the exception cause, but it only passes it into the superclass constructor (note the absence of `val` before the second parameter). It also takes advantage of default arguments in Kotlin, which allows you to not specify the cause.

Unfortunately, you can't use a data class specifically in your case for the reason that their primary constructors aren't allowed to have regular arguments. You'd have to declare the cause as a property as well. Data classes are supposed to be used for the simplest cases, and you have a more complex one.

If the superclass needs to be initialized with two different constructors conditionally, then you will have to use two different constructors in your class as well. Any constructor must either delegate superclass initialization to another constructor or do that itself. It can't do both because that would mean that the superclass is initialized twice, which doesn't make sense. Also both superclass initialization and delegation happen before the constructor is executed itself, so you can't have any logic regarding which one to do.

You can't have a primary constructor because it always needs to be delegated to when present. That means that the properties will have to be declared explicitly as well, as the property declaration and initialization syntax only applies to the primary constructor.

Comment: Thanks. This and @holi-java's answer are both great for the `Exception` case, as Exception allows a null cause and handles it correctly. The more general issue of not being able to call different super constructors and also use `var`/`val` parameters remains unanswered.

Comment: @YonaAppletree In short, that's not possible. But in case you are looking for an explanation, I've added it to the answer.

Answer (score 3):

Since both `this(...)` & `super(...)` is the first statement in a constructor, so you can't call it simultaneously. otherwise, you will obtain a compile-time error.

**IF** any classes contains a [primary constructor](http://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/classes.html#constructors), their [secondary constructors](http://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/classes.html#constructors) must call its primary constructor explictly, so you can't call additional `super(...)` on secondary constructor at all.

> if the class has a primary constructor, each secondary constructor needs to delegate to the primary constructor, either directly or indirectly through another secondary constructor(s). Delegation to another constructor of the same class is done using the `this` keyword

But there is another way to set the cause by [Throwable#initCause](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Throwable.html#initCause-java.lang.Throwable-), for example:

```
data class MyException(val extraData: Any) : RuntimeException() {
    constructor(extraData: Any, cause: Throwable) : this(extraData) {
        initCause(cause)
    }
}
```

**AND** the [data class](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/data-classes.html) is designed for [POJO](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plain_old_Java_object) rather than `Exception`s.